# Sum Identities and the uniqueness of Sin and Cos

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, power-series

The below problem I am having a hard time solving. I suspect that there is some property that characterizes $\sin$ and $\cos$ and using that together with the Uniqueness Theorem (Identity Theorem) we can reach the conclusion.

> Let $S(z)$, $C(z)$ be power series convergent for all complex numbers, satisfying the identities:
> $$S(z+w) = S(z)C(w) + S(w)C(z)$$
> $$C(z+w) = C(z)C(w)-S(z)S(w)$$
> $$C(0)=1, S(0)=0.$$
> Prove that for some $m \in \mathbb{C}$, $S(z) = \sin (mz), C(z) = \cos(mz)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

One idea I had was to at least try to deduce the Pythagorean Identity. So I defined $F(z) = [C(z)]^2+[S(z)]^2$. I was able to show $F(2z) = [F(z)]^2$ for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent let z=w, for the sum equations - then use the definition of $F$.

Comment: I get it now, thanks.

Comment: Let $E(z)=C(z)+iS(z)$.Then the equations you want to prove amount to $E(z)=e^{imz}$, and the sum equations you're given amount to $E(z+w)=E(z)E(w)$. So $\ln E$, which is well-defined at least near $0$ because $E(0)=1$, is additive. It follows that $E$ is linear on rational numbers, hence by continuity on real numbers, hence by holomorphicity on complex numbers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124887.